# Subviews not clipped on swipe left to delete UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm simply trying to implement swipe left and hit the delete button to remove a UITableViewCell.

On touch, the cell expands/contracts. The full size of the cell has been designed using Xcode and I have "Clip Subviews" ticked in order to prevent the bottom of the cell appearing in the contracted state.

However, when I swipe left on the contracted cell (to show the delete button), the bottom of the cell reappears! I've searched around for a solution but have yet to find one. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am running into the same thing. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I use `SWTableViewCell` now for all my swiping needs for Table View Cells.

Comment: Thanks. (I assume this is iOS8). I didn't have the problem under iOS7.

Comment: Believe it was just iOS 8 yes

Answer (score 3):

*Full credit to Vitaliy Gozhenko, I am just duplicating an answer here. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432095/uitableviewcell-not-clipping-to-bounds-in-editing-mode-in-ios8-works-in-ios7-1/27452952#27452952)*.

The issue is that `cell.contentView.clipsToBounds` is getting set to `NO` when the table enters edit mode.

To fix

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

for me this was the fix needed for iOS8.