# UITableViewCell not clipping to bounds in editing mode in iOS8 (works in iOS7.1)

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

I am setting the height of a UITableViewCell so that it will clip and not all the content for the row is visible. This works fine in iOS7 both "not edit" mode and "edit" mode. In iOS8 it is only working in "not edit" mode. When editing the entire content of the cell is shown **after the red delete button on the left is tapped so that you see the delete button on the right.**

I had been setting `cell.clipsToBounds = YES` and thought this was all I needed to do.

**EDIT**: I also tried `cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES` but this didn't work.

**iOS7: (this is what I want)**

[image]

**iOS8:**

[image]

Comment: Did you tried `cell.contentView.clipToBounds = YES`?

Comment: Yes, just tried `cell.contentView.clipsToBounds` (with a 's') an few minutes ago to no avail (I'll add this info).

Comment: can you post your cell's nib file? I want to check your autolayout settings. If you do it in storyboard, can you copy cell from storyboard to separate nib and share?

Comment: also how do you change cell height? Via UITableView heightForRowAtIndexPath and reloading cell?

Comment: 1) Looking at the constraints I am embarrassed (fixed width textField?? -- all I can say is that it's old!). Here is the xib. [Here is the xib](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dyaa5fqp7lwyhqf/ForVitaliy.xib?dl=0).

Comment: 2) Yes, `UITableView heightForRowAtIndexPath`. The `UISwitch` state determines the height of the cell, the cell reloads when the switch changes state.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like the UITableView in iOS 8 set cell.contentView.clipToBounds to NO when begin editing. This code help me resolve your issue:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

Comment: AMAZING! One tweak. `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath` is called only on swipe. The problem here was after the user tapped the left-hand delete indicator to get the Delete confirmation on the right. It would have been the same for swipe, I never thought to try it. I used 
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to set `clipsToBounds = YES`. This fixes it. But maybe heavy handed.

Answer (score 5):

I tried **Vitaliy** and **ToddB's** solutions and unfortunately they were not always 100% consistent for me although they did work most of the time.

I hate to have to override layoutSubviews but I've found no other solution that works 100% of the time thus far :'(

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: It's a shame these kinds of things are needed.

Comment: Yea its too bad, I would submit a bug report but, they'd probably just tell me I'm using the API incorrectly.